# How to adapt spring security to work with Ali Cloud's OAuth2 endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to get spring-oauth2 to work with Ali Cloud's OAuth endpoint. I have the following in my application.yml.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          alicloud:
            clientId: foo
            clientSecret: bar
            redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
        provider:
          alicloud:
            authorizationUri: https://signin.aliyun.com/oauth2/v1/auth
            tokenUri: https://oauth.aliyun.com/v1/token
            jwkSetUri: https://oauth.aliyun.com/v1/keys
```

Things seem to get to the point where the code needs to be exchanged for an access_token. However,  `DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse` seems to package the request with HTTP Basic authentication. This works for Google and I imagine most of the rest of the big providers. But Ali Cloud's endpoint requires the client_id and client_secret in the POST body. The converter that seems to create this request is `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter`. It doesn't seem easy to override it.

What can I do to overcome this?